# convert json response to an array which can be used for d3 funnel chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

example json:

```
{
    "json_data": [
        {
            "budget": 1000,
            "Actual": "3468.000 "
        },
        {
            "budget": 2000,
            "Actual": "7905.000 "
        },
        {
            "budget": 3000,
            "Actual": "7454.000 "
        },
        {
            "budget": 4000,
            "Actual": "3671.000 "
        },
        {
            "budget": 5000,
            "Actual": "5875.000 "
        },
        {
            "budget": 6000,
            "Actual": "6157.000 "
        },
        {
            "budget": 7000,
            "Actual": "7520.000 "
        },
        {
            "budget": 8000,
            "Actual": "2251.000 "
        },
        {
            "budget": 9000,
            "Actual": ""
        },
        {
            "budget": 10000,
            "Actual": ""
        },
        {
            "budget": 11000,
            "Actual": ""
        },
        {
            "budget": 12000,
            "Actual": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

to ARRAY OF THIS FORMAT:

```
vardata=[
    [
        'VideoViews',
        1500
    ],
    [
        'Comments',
        1000
    ],
    [
        'VideoResponses',
        900
    ],
    [
        'VideoViews',
        1500
    ],
    [
        'Comments',
        1000
    ],
    [
        'VideoResponses',
        900
    ]
];
```

Comment: How is the input object maps to the array?

Comment: Where do the numbers and the strings in the "output" array come from?

Comment: hi, the output array is an example set, what i want is - to map the json object into an array of that format.

Comment: my aim is to draw a d3 funnel, when i send the post the response comes to me in the above mentioned json format, now d3 works only with arrays and the array structure looks like the one i hv given in the example.

Comment: sharing with you the d3 link, https://github.com/smilli/d3-funnel-charts

Comment: Plese provide some more details what exactly you want

Comment: what i want is to change the JSON data to an array. The format of the array is the one i have mentioned, for example: var data=[ [['budget',1000],['actual',66767]],[['budget',2000],['actual',367367]]]

Comment: hi the response looks perfect, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i might do it. In short, you are trying to convert an array of object to an array of array.

```
output = [] // this will become  an array of array

// assuming json_data is store in example    

for (var i=0;i< (example['json_data']).length;i++){
    var entry = exmple['json_data'][i] 
    output.push(['budget', entry['budget']]);
    output.push(['Actual',entry['Actual']]);
```

}

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
// [["budget",1000],["Actual","3468.000 "],["budget",2000],\
// ["Actual","7905.000 "],["budget",3000] ... ] //
```

Comment: if this is what you are looking for could you please accept it as an answer by clicking on the arrow besides the question ? thanks! cheers

Comment: hi, this is my frst q on stackoverflow, am unable to find that arrow which u jst asked to click